# Chrome based slideshow app for ChromeCast

Tags: google-chrome-extension, slideshow, google-chrome-app, chromecast

I am trying to write a simple chrome app to play a sequence of online pictures on my chromecast device.
I have looked at some examples, but could't find anything which I could tweak around to get the simple behavior i needed. Maybe someone here could help, by providing directions or advise on getting started with developing something like that for chromecast.

UPDATE: 
To give you a better idea, about the specifics, let me add some more details to my requirements.

- It needs to be controlled from chrome
- I want to pass a playlist with 10s-100s of images so it can slide them in circles.
- After receiving playlist chromecast device should be able to continue on its own, without continuously asking for next image.

This is actually similar to backdrop feature Google is planning to introduce, but I wanted to write something myself.

Thanks

Comment: Voted back up to zero because I object to anyone voting down without a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to develop your own Cast receiver, then you can use the media namespace channel and the Styled Media Receiver to display a photo at a time:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver
You will have to add the logic to advance from photo to photo in your sender app.

If you are willing to develop your own custom receiver, then you can start with this Cast sample app:
https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android

It allows you to send messages to a custom receiver. You can use that to send the URLs of the photos and then you can add JavaScript logic in the receiver to play a slideshow.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some updates to my question with specifics. One of them is that I am looking for developing Chrome App/extension. Is there anything like that for Chrome? You mentioned SMR, but from what I understood it is for video/audio, but I couldn't find anything for photo playlist.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, I have tried various options and ended up writing [custom receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) and [Chrome sender](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender) applications. This was really straightforward and exactly what I wanted.

See the links above for guidance and also examples [here](https://github.com/googlecast).

Comment: Instead of asking the same question many times and waiting for two weeks, you could have done it already yourself. This is not a freelancer website, no one is going to do your work for you. The link above has all the information I used to solve this, should be enough for you too.